# while liste[i] != " ": is list index problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Problem is in line 11. It says:

> while liste[i] != " ":
>   IndexError: list index out of range

When I send small texts, there is not any problem. (example 2000 letters) Program works very well. But if there are many letters (example 41220 letters), it says list index error.
Thanks for help :)

```
def kelimelere_Ayir(metin):
    liste = list(metin)
    n = len(liste)
    kelime = ""
    a = ""
    kelimeler = []
    i = 0
    while i != n:

        if liste[i] != " ":
            while liste[i] != " ":   ### PROBLEM IS HERE.
                kelime += liste[i]
                i += 1
            kelimeler.append(kelime)
            kelime = a
        else:
            i += 1
    return kelimeler
```

Comment: list index error means that you are trying to get something from a list at an index that is not in the list, for example having a list of 3 elements and asking for index of 3 (available indexes are 0, 1, 2)

Comment: Think, trace and simulate what might happen if say, there were *no spaces* in `liste`. You may want to try small and minimal examples of `metin` and `liste` first before attempting big solutions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the code is intended to do, but there are a couple of things I wonder about: (1) In Python, you can index strings like lists, so I don't think it's necessary to convert the argument to a list right away, and (2) this looks a lot like you are trying to split a string at whitespace, and the string method `split` might save you some work. (On the other hand, writing equivalents to library functions/methods is often a good way to learn how things work!)

Answer (score 1):

use `while i < n and liste[i] != " ":` and run again